# How to obtain XML encoding type?

Tags: dataweave

My current payload is (received from a POST)

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>
<test>
</test>
```

I want to get the encoding value (ie `ISO-8859-1`)

What is the correct DataWeave expression to use ?

I already tested

```
var infos = payload.^mediaType splitBy "; "
var encoding = infos[1] splitBy  "="
---
media:
{ 
    mime: infos[0],
    encoding: encoding[1]
}
```

But it return me:

```
{
"mime": "application/xml",
"encoding": "UTF-8"
}
```

It seems `payload.^mediaType` is coming from my POST headers.

Here is the solution to the problem:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
((payload.^raw as String) scan /encoding='([A-z0-9-]+)'/)[0][1]
```

In the proposed solution the ^ symbol is missing.

Answer (score 9):

Sadly there is no elegant way to do this. The only way I thought is by using regex.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
((payload.^raw as String) scan /encoding='([A-z0-9-]+)'/)[0][1]
```

This is going to return the encoding.

Comment: The propose solution is not working, to make it work please replace `payload.raw` by `payload.^raw`